# How do I ShaDon't?

Tags: neovim

I really don't care about any of the "value" that viminfo or its replacement in neovim, ShaDa, provide. I couldn't care less about whether or not my cursor is in the exact place I left it when I open a file or whether my registers are restored, but I am very tired of seeing seemingly random ShaDa-related errors. Is there a way that I can just turn off shared data? `:help shada` has not been very helpful in this endeavor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`set shada="NONE"` will prevent shada files from being generated or read in Neovim.

For vim, `set viminfo="NONE"` will disable viminfo files.

Comment: Surely those double quotes are wrong?

Answer (score 6):

According to [the neovim docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#-i), if you invoke neovim with `-i NONE`, it will ignore the ShaDa file.

Insert the following into your bashrc:

```
alias nvim='nvim -i NONE'
```

Comment: I expected `-u NONE` to ignore all local config, including shada, but it doesn't; you have to use `-u NONE -i NONE` (or `--clean` to disable both vimrc and shada). Was driving me nuts when neovim hung for 10 seconds on `:q` because shada was trying to access files on an ephemeral mounted filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for the same answer but in Lua. You can set in your init.lua file:

```
vim.opt.shadafile = "NONE"
```